# JPA -- Cannot instantiate abstract class exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

**FundOperationItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATION_ITEMS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "D_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class FundOperationItem implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_OPERATION_ID", nullable=false)
   private FundOperation operation;

   public FundOperation getOperation() {
      return this.operation;
   }

   public void setOperation(final FundOperation operation) {
      this.operation = operation;
   }

}
```

**ExchangeOperationItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXCHANGE_OPERATION_ITEMS")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="2")
public class ExchangeOperationItem extends FundOperationItem {

}
```

**SimpleOperationItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIMPLE_OPERATION_ITEMS")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="1")
public class SimpleOperationItem extends FundOperationItem {

}
```

**FundOperation.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATIONS")
public class FundOperation implements java.io.Serializable{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "operation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<FundOperationItem> operationItems = new ArrayList<FundOperationItem>();

    public List<FundOperationItem> getOperationItems() {
        return this.operationItems;
    }

    public void setOperationItems(final List<FundOperationItem> operationItems) {
        this.operationItems = operationItems;
    }

}
```

Using this in such manner:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    FundOperation oper = operationRepository.findById(1L);
    System.out.println(oper.getOperationItems().size());
}
```

Got such exception:

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate abstract class of type "rba.pm.persistency.operation.FundOperationItem" with object id "rba.pm.persistency.operation.FundOperationItem-1"; this may indicate that the inheritance discriminator for the class is not configured correctly.

DB content:

```
Insert into OPERATIONS (OPERATION_ID) values (1);
Insert into OPERATIONS (OPERATION_ID) values (2);
Insert into OPERATIONS (OPERATION_ID) values (3);

Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (1,1,1);
Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (2,2,1);
Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (3,3,1);

Insert into SIMPLE_OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID) values (1);
Insert into SIMPLE_OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID) values (2);
Insert into SIMPLE_OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID) values (3);
```

Have I made something wrong?

#### Update:

**There is an solution, if add to the test above a new line

```
    SimpleOperationItem sio = new SimpleOperationItem();
```

it works

```
    @Test
    public void test(){
        SimpleOperationItem sio = new SimpleOperationItem();
        FundOperation oper = operationRepository.findById(1L);
        System.out.println(oper.getOperationItems().size());
    }
```

Note: Object 'sio' does not have any relation to 'oper'.

Any idea, what is going on? 
Is this a problem with classloader? 
Is this a known problem?

Comment: Does the row you're trying to find has 1 or 2 in the D_TYPE column?

Comment: Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (1,1,1);

Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (2,2,1);
Insert into OPERATION_ITEMS (OPERATION_ITEM_ID,PARENT_OPERATION_ID,D_TYPE) values (3,3,1);

Comment: For sake of experiment - could you try changing discriminatorType from INTEGER to STRING? Also, are you sure you've conserved all the significant parts of persistent classes while preparing code samples for question? E.g., you omitted PKs in entities. I'm just wondering if there's something you missed, and the real situation differs from what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for comment: I tried -- but nothing chaged.

Comment: Actually, there is an solution.
VERY unexpected, but: if add to the test above a new line 
        `SimpleOperationItem sio = new SimpleOperationItem();`
everything works just perfectly.... Note: SimpleOperationItem is a child of FundOperationItem. So ifinstantiate it -- it will be possible to resolve it via its super class...

**Any idea, what is going on?**
Is this a problem with classloader? 
Is this a known problem?

Comment: How is your project organized? Just now noticed that you are using OpenJPA, and afair instrumentation was required for OpenJPA project to work; could you double-check everything works fine with instrumentation process (before tests)?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this, but try the following in `FundOperationItem`:

```
@DiscriminatorValue(value="0")
```